# How do I pass variables into Twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

In my preprocess function I have variables with the route name and route parameters:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  $variables['route_name'] = $route_name;
  $variables['route_parameters'] = $route_parameters;
}
```

How do I pass them to the following link function in my page.html.twig file:

```
{ <a href="{{ path('$route_name', {'node': $route_parameters}) }}">Link to the object with $route_name and $route_parameters</a> }
```

Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '$' isn't used in twig to designate a variable. This code should work:

```
<a href="{{ path(route_name, {'node': route_parameters}) }}">
   Link to the object with {{ route_name }} and {{ route_parameters }}
</a>
```